Variance of dollar gamma
Let us assume we are in the Black-Scholes model. I define cash gamma as $CG=S^2_t∗Γ(t,S_t)$, assuming interest rates are 0 to simplify. Then I would like to compute $E(S^4_tΓ^2(t,S_t))$. As We already know that $E(S^2_tΓ(t,S^t))=S^2_0Γ(0,S_0)$
I get it from hedging error derivation, and $E(S^4_tΓ^2(t,S_t))\approx S^4_0Γ(0,S_0)^2\sqrt{T^2/T^2-t^2} $
This is similar question to unsolved question
enter link description here
